# Jobs filters "Ooops, something went wrong!"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In the Jobs section, whenever I add a tech or compensation, and click "Apply Filters", I get error popup "Ooops, something went wrong!", and the filters don't work.

Details: 
On Chrome an Firefox, logged in, no user scripts running.

I had this error in the console: GET https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/so-proxy/jobs 500

After logging out it worked.

After logging back in, the error returned.

Comment: No repro here (Windows, Chrome 75). Can you add details, such as logged in/logged out, browser version, userscripts if any, etc.

Comment: @ErikA added all the details :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a blip with the process that indexes jobs for search purposes. I've given it a kick and you should be all set. Apologies for the inconvenience.

**Update**

There was a case here that we hadn't accounted for - notably when a user's job preferences contained a disliked tag and a search was performed explicitly for that tag and only a few jobs came back from the search then the weighting algorithm generated an array index that couldn't be dereffed back into the array of jobs we were processing. That threw an exception and caused a 500 on the backend.

Fix is rolling out to production now.

Comment: ok but still getting the error though =[ is it just me ? ?

Comment: @Andrew I see the error you’re hitting in the logs, I’ll dig tomorrow. Apologies!

Comment: @Andrew in the process of fixing now, strange edge case :/

Comment: @Andrew fix is in prod